# Overflow element inside hidden div not showing properly after show using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry if this question was asked before. I've tried finding the solution, and found nothing that related to my problem.

I use jQuery to implement show/hide div. Then I found out that my overflow element inside the hidden div does not show properly after I click `show toggle`.

Refer to the images below.

This is the problem:

[image: Problem]

And the intended solution:

[image: Solution]

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnStart').on('click', function() {
    $('#socmedInstagram').slideDown();
  });
});
```

```css
.container-tombol {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
height: auto;
}

.tombol-merah1 {
background-image: url('img/lucky-draw-circle.png');
background-size: 80px;
position: absolute;
top: -50px;
bottom: -50px;
left: -30px;
right: -30px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index: 1;
pointer-events: none;
width: 250px;
}

.continue-div {
text-align: center;
margin: 5% 0;"
}

.container-title {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
height: auto;
}

 .title-bar1 {
 background-image: 
 url('img/lucky-draw-title-bar-
 instagram.png');
 background-size: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: -40px;
 bottom: -40px;
 left: -170px;
 right: -170px;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 z-index: 1;
 pointer-events: none;
 width: 330px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnStart">Start Now!</button>
<div class="row" id="socmedInstagram" style="display: none;">
  <div class="container-tombol">
    <div class="tombol-merah1">
      <h1 style="margin: 0 auto; font-family: 'Airstrike'; color: white; font-size:50px; position: absolute; left: 25px; right: 25px; top: 8px; bottom: 8px;">1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-title">
    <div class="title-bar1">
      <h1 style="margin: 0 auto; font-family: 'BigNoodleTitling'; text-shadow:  0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); font-weight: 200; font-style: oblique; color: white; font-size:28px; position: absolute; left: 20px; right: 20px; top: 13px; bottom: 13px;">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> &nbsp;Follow My Instagram</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card" style="border: 0;">
      <div class="card-block" style="padding: 25px;">
        <div class="continue-div">
          <h1 style="font-size: 33px; font-family: 'BigNoodleTitling'; font-style: Oblique;">Thank you for Following us on Instagram!</h1>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnContinueInstagram">Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really appreciate any kind of solution that can help me out. May I know if you guys have a better method to make something like this. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: check z-index with relative positioning.

Comment: @Rafee , i've tried out playing with z-index and the overflow element still hiding. can i know more specifically. thanks

Comment: Show your CSS as well please.

Comment: @hanif , okey. css added. thanks

Comment: Add `overflow:auto;` to the element in question to correct this well-known bug (ahem, feature).

Comment: Also (FYI), replace `.live` with `.on` as `.live` was deprecated some time ago.

Comment: @ScottMarcus , overflow:auto; not working for me. i hope you can leave me specific explaination. thanks! i appreciate that.

Comment: do u have a fiddle?

Comment: I think there's still some html missing, what is your div `#socmedInstagram` a child of? what are the styles on that?

Comment: my #socmedInstagram is in div.container . btw, everything's solved. I fix it with a tricky way which i put the keyframe animation on the hidden overflow.